# Ruby - Grouping data from CSV file by a column

Tags: ruby, csv, group-by

I have a CSV file that looks like this:

```
+---------+----------+
|  Name   |  Stream  |
+---------+----------+
| Jacob   | Computer |
| Ryan    | Arts     |
| Bob     | Computer |
| Charlie | Science  |
| Grace   | Arts     |
+---------+----------+
```

I need to read this CSV file and group the students based on their stream. The output should be like this:

```
Computer
----------
Jacob
Bob

Arts
------
Ryan
Grace

Science
--------
Charlie
```

I tried to use `group_by`, but was not sure how and where to use it. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Is that what you literally have? Then that is not a CSV file.

Comment: Show what you tried.

Comment: What I have is indeed a csv file; I have just put it down in a tabular format so that it looks better and is easier to read and understand.

Comment: Also as I mentioned, since I am new to the language I am not sure on the approach that I should take to get this done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you have csv file with the following content:

```
Name,Stream
Jacob,Computer
Ryan,Arts
Bob,Computer
Charlie,Science
Grace,Arts
```

You can use something like this

```
require 'csv'    

result = {}
file = File.read('path_to_your_file')
csv = CSV.parse(file, headers: true)
csv.each do |row|
  if result[row[1]]
    result[row[1]].push row[0]
  else
    result[row[1]] = [row[0]]
  end
end
```

You'll get `result` variable containing a hash where every stream will be associated with an array of names

Comment: Great, that works beautifully. Right now my output is    {"Computer"=>["Jacob", "Bob"], "Arts"=>["Ryan", "Grace"], "Science"=>["Charlie"]}  What would help is if I could get it in the format of course name followed by the student names in separate lines (as illustrated in the question). I am trying to do that but the fact that the 'result' is an array seems to be making it slightly more complicated.

Comment: `result.keys.each { |key| puts; puts.key; puts '-----'; result[key].each { |val| puts val } }`

Comment: Perfect! You might want to remove the . character in the `puts.key` statement

Comment: sure, but I can't :)